# How to Create split URL in 2 different variables

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0, urlsplit

Reset Password link (Cakephp 3.8.4)

```php
$link = urldecode(
    Router::url(
        array(
            "action" => "resetpassword",
            base64_encode($_REQUEST['phone_email_forgot'])
        ),
        true
    )
);
```

url :

```
http://example.in/index/resetpassword/bWQua2F5cmFAZ21haWwuY29t
```

How I can split the URL above and create variables like `$link_1`

```
http://example.in/index/resetpassword/
```

and `$link_2`

```
bWQua2F5cmFAZ21haWwuY29t
```

I need to use this for Sending SMS purpose as `{#var#}` accept maximum 30 characters only.

Please help me with this.

Regards,
Anand

Comment: Why do you generate a combined URL in the first place? Why not generate the two things separately from the get go? Also why are you using base64 encoded E-Mail addresses if you have a 30 char limit? Addresses can be way longer than 30 chars, and base64 only inflates the number of characters!

Comment: How to make these two things separately as I want part 1 as host like http://example.in/index/resetpassword/ which concat with part 2 as encrypted code and will use as(#var#)  please help

Comment: I have created variable code for base64 encoded which I want to contact with prefix URL in href tag **$code = urldecode(base64_encode($_REQUEST['phone_email_forgot']),true);** like this but i didnt get any result. Get URL but without $code Please someone help.